# optimizers other than GradientDescentOptimizer tensorflow having zero for gradient value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am really at wit's end and don't know where else I can ask so I am asking here. I know that my question may not be of the best quality but I am hoping for at least some guidance on the direction I should look to figure out my problem.

I am replicating sci-kit learn's implementation of Elastic Net Multiple Linear Regression in tensorflow and tensorboard as a learning exercise so I can eventually move on to implement and visualize more difficult machine learning algorithms.

I have some code that does a Multiple Linear Regression using the [Elastic Net Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization) as the loss function. With gradient descent, it converges to a suboptimal solution compared to sci-kit learn's [algorithm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html). Through some searching, I learned that sci-kit learn initializes weights using the Xavier method, so I did that in tensorflow as well. Performance improved slightly but still was no where close to sklearn. My next improvement was to change the optimizer to attempt to match performance although my research told me that scikit learn uses [coordinate descent](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24907/what-optimization-algorithms-are-used-in-scikit-learn) which is a method that isn't implemented in tensorflow.

However, this is where I am stuck. It seems that simply switching out the optimizer for another optimizer does not seem to work (not that I expected it to, but I'm also having trouble finding material that will tell me how to set up properly). Currently I've simply performed the switch the following way, can anyone give me a hint why my gradients are 0?

Thanks!

```
# Declare optimizer
my_opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
my_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(epsilon = 0.1)
```

[Histogram of gradients:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlC7c.png)

[image]

[Loss function showing that Adam optimizer isn't doing anything:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKofQ.png)
[image]

EDIT:

I have updated my learning rate to be higher, but convergence still doesn't seem that great. I think I will proceed to try to implement Coordinate Descent in tensorflow to match sci-kit learn's method as close as possible. I've attached an image of the difference for those curious:

[image: Red = 0.5, Blue= 0.1, Orange = 0.01]

In comparison to SGD:

[image]

Comment: default learning rate of Adam is quite small, try to increase it. Also, your loss is gigantic, are you sure your implementation is correct? You might hit serious numerical issues with values so huge.

Comment: I agree with lejlot. With gradients and losses so huge, I expect your regression weights and/or inputs were very large. Many optimizers like Adam will normalize the gradients in some way, which, multiplied by learning rate, may then be insignificant compared to the weights. Please try normalizing the regression inputs/outputs, e.g. using z-scores.

Comment: I've normalized my inputs using z-scores, but not the target. I'll try it normalizing my output as well but I thought that it wasn't [necessary](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re). I'll also try increasing the learning rate and report back. Thanks!